# Moment.js giving tomorow and yesterday in reverse

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My console:

[image]

same w/o new Date constructor:

[image]

What can be wrong??

PS: it is not project related because I am getting same results in console on momentjs.com

EDIT:
To easily reproduce, go to momentjs.com, open console, put:

```
moment().calendar('2016-11-27T07:31:29.000+0000'); // expecting "Sunday at 9:58 AM" getting "Tuesday at 9:58 AM"
moment().calendar('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000'); // expecting "Yesterday at 9:58 AM" getting "Tomorrow at 9:58 AM"
moment().calendar('2016-11-29T07:31:29.000+0000'); // this is correct "Today at 9:58 AM"
moment().calendar('2016-11-30T07:31:29.000+0000'); // expecting "Tomorrow at 9:58 AM" getting "Yesterday at 9:58 AM"
```

Comment: Can you check what the ``new Date(...)`` parses to? That is ``console.log(new Date(...))``. I think one of the problems Moment.JS solves, is the Date parsing behaving awkward here and there. So, I would use Moments own date parser to start with.

Comment: Maybe like this `moment('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000').calendar()` ?

Comment: @Andrey same result:
moment('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000').calendar()
"Yesterday at 8:31 AM"

Comment: @Luckylooke, thats not the same result :P

Comment: @tiblu new Date('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000')
Mon Nov 28 2016 08:31:29 GMT+0100 (CET)

Comment: @Andrey aa correct :D Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) it says:

```
moment().calendar(referenceTime);
```

Calendar time displays time relative to a given referenceTime (defaults to now), but does so slightly differently than moment#fromNow

So the results what you get is correct, because your string time is reference.

For the correct result use:

```
moment('2016-11-30T07:31:29.000+0000').calendar();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.calendar()`'s second parameter is the reference time. [Docs Here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/)

if you're trying to change the date of something. instead, create it like:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar()
```

or

```
moment('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000').calendar()
```

Answer (score 0):

So as @Andrey pointed the correct order is:

```
moment('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000').calendar()
```

not

```
moment().calendar('2016-11-28T07:31:29.000+0000')
```

Thank you @Andrey